# Retrieve iPhone battery usage and cycles

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to retrieve battery informations and more precisely the battery usage and the cycles count for my iPhone.

I built a Flutter app and I saw these two useful packages :

- https://pub.dev/packages/battery_plus
- https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus

With both packages, I'm able to retrieve main informations about my smartphone but they not permit to access to battery usage and total cycles of the battery.

Do you have an idea or an hint to obtain these informations directly from Flutter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS doesn't offer an API for detailed battery information, so it's not possible on iPhone (and if you do somehow find a workaround, you would have to use a private API, which could get your app rejected from the store).

So the info you can get from those packages you mentioned is the best you can do without hacking your phone.